# Google app: domain verification for Oauth is successful, but status remains "Pending developer action"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-search-console

I'm working on getting a Google app verified, and although I have completed the domain verification, the Oauth consent screen says that it is waiting on me to "comply with domain verification requirements." What does this mean?

**1.** I've confirmed that I completed domain verification at https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home. (With my personal google account, I verified the domain with a DNS TXT record, then delegated it to my work account.)

---

[image]

---

**2.** ...and I've set that domain as the sole authorised domain for my app...

[image]

---

**3.** Nevertheless, the Oauth consent screen says that I still need to comply with the domain verification requirements. Why would this be?

---

[image]

Comment: Your identity is not the owner. You are a delegated owner which means the owner added you. Most likely there is a problem with the owner identity. For example the "owner" identity's status changed to not verified which then prevents delegated identities from being verified.

Comment: I've checked John Hanley's comment, and although this identity is not the owner, this identity _was_ granted all privileges. This app has subsequently been approved, confirming that it is fine to submit this for approval using a non-owner identity.

Comment: I have identical issue. I did all the confirmations that @JellicleCat describes, plus I verified in IAM settings that I am the owner of the GCP project. Could it matter that the project owner's email is "FirstLastname@mydomain.com" and my identity in GCP & Search Console is "firstlastname@mydomain.com"?

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. I've been using either for years. Do you know how I can change the owner to "firstlastname@mydomain.com"?

Comment: @JohnPankowicz https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access?visit_id=637964290038830761-606483340&rd=1#grant-single-role

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. I enter the email without the caps & ignore their suggestion to use the one with caps. But in the "Select a role" dropdown, it shows "Owner" as a role "Currently used". I select it anyway and click Save. But IAM -> Permissions never get changed. Maybe I need to change it to someone completely different first? Or perhaps I need to make this a separate question?

Comment: @JohnPankowicz - I recommend creating a new question with details.

Comment: I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73406087/how-to-transfer-google-cloud-project-ownership-from-myemailmydomain-com-to-myem)

Answer (score 5):

Once you have completed the actions specified under "Pending developer action", you will need to reach back out to the Google verification team to inform them that you've taken action for your app verification to proceed. See https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#zippy=%2Cpending-developer-action.

Comment: But I didn't receive an email, or get an email to reply/respond back to? What do I do now?

Comment: @JamesBarnett, what do you did?

Comment: @PhabluloJoel Turns out, when I made the cloud version of the project it made two instead of one. You need to make sure that you click the right cloud project.