# How to transfer Google Cloud project ownership from MyEmail@mydomain.com to myemail@mydomain.com?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

For years, I've been using the email addresses MyEmail@mydomain.com and myemail@mydomain.com as if they are identical. And most of the time this is true. However now the OAuth verification process for the project seems to be failing because Google treats these as two separate identities.

The GCP project owner is MyEmail@mydomain.com. In the OAuth consent screen, I've set mydomain.com as the sole authorized domain for my app. And I use myemail@mydomain.com as my identity in Google Search Console when verifying that I am the owner of mydomain.com.

I got an email from the "The Google Cloud Trust & Safety Team", saying that the owner of the GCP project and the identity of the owner of the authorized domain do not match! The only reason for this seems to be the case of the email names, because everything else appears set up properly.

MY QUESTION: **How can I change the GCP project owner from MyEmail@mydomain.com to myemail@mydomain.com?**

It seems that I need to change one or the other. I would rather change the GCP owner to myemail@mydomain.com. But I can not get that to happen. I followed the instructions in [Grant or Revoke Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access?visit_id=637964290038830761-606483340&rd=1#grant-single-role).

I go to IAM -> Permissions - Add. I enter the email without the caps & ignore their suggestion to use the one with caps. But in the "Select a role" dropdown, it shows "Owner" as a role "Currently used". I select it anyway and click Save. But IAM -> Permissions never get changed.

I've thought of changing the owner first to someone completely different and then to the lower case email. But that might involve billing emails changing, etc.

EDIT - As a result of trying to add myemail@mydomain.com to the project, I received an email at that address from GCP, asking me to join the project. I accepted the request, but IAM is still only showing MyEmail@mydomain.com as being on the project.

Is this really the case that myemail@mydomain.com and MyEmail@mydomain.com are separate GCP identities? Might there be a different reason for Trust & Safety to think they're not the same?

**If I respond to the T&S email, describing my issue, will a real person actually read it, or will the same automated test be run again to check the issue?**

**Resolution:** I responded to the T&S email, explaining what was going on with the upper/lower case letters in my email address.
Today I got a reply: **"Request Granted.** Your project is now verified for ....". That's great! But I wonder if I will forever be first rejected for the same reason on all new projects that I create. It appears that the final solution is likely finding a way to change my logon email on GCP to one without capital letters.

Comment: I am not sure that the removal of a project owner IAM role from a user is to affect a billing accout - are you sure about that?

Comment: I think your hypothesis is correct. IIRC this also happens if you were to use e.g. `my.email@mydomain.com` (note the `.`) which is treated by Google (elsehwere) as a synonym for `myemail@mydomain.com` but I think **not** with Google Cloud. Do you have Cloud Support? I'd recommend contacting Google, explaining this and seeing whether an engineer can effect the change for you. A Google Account has a unique GAIA ID and, the system must use the email address as a poor proxy for the GAIA ID. Only Google would be able to make this change.

Comment: Adding (!) a temporary owner is another solution though because you're updating the project's (only) `Owner`, I worry that a mis-step would cause you additional problems.

Comment: I don't have Cloud support. Doesn't adding a temporary owner involve the same steps I described that I did above, but with just adding a Condition? That IAM form refuses to recognize the lower case email as being different from the uppercase. I also tried adding the lowercase email as "Editor" since the Trust & Safety Team will accept that role on the project for verification. But all it did was add "Editor" to the roles that the uppercase email has.

Comment: There is a slight possibility that this is a [conflicting account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181526?hl=en&ref_topic=7189049) related issue. Are you by any chance asked to select between a `Personal` or `Business` profile when trying to log into your Google account?

Comment: @FernandoLara I've never been asked that when logging in.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that you are never asked to select a different profile when logging into your account, then it should be the exact same account using the actual same GAIA ID as mentioned by [DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin), so there should be no difference within the GCP console between MyEmail@mydomain.com and myemail@mydomain.com.

Google usually recognizes an email address in both forms as the same account, although there are some exceptions across their products (I have had a similar experience with email addresses from Google Groups). I think this is one of those particular exceptions.

I would strongly recommend transferring the project ownership to a totally different account within your domain, then waiting a couple of hours due to Google's "propagation time" across services, and transferring the ownership back to the account using the format `myemail@mydomain.com`.

Now answering to:

> If I respond to the T&S email, describing my issue, will a real person actually read it, or will the same automated test be run again to check the issue?

They are actually a team of people, but they tend to use a lot of canned responses, so I would definitively recommend being very specific with your choice of words when responding to their emails otherwise, you may not get a relevant response. You may also try to explain this to them via email to see if there is an actual problem with the email address or if it is just them or the system being extremely picky when checking the email address.

Comment: You are likely right, that transferring ownership twice is the only solution. I tried adding the uppercase email as a delegated owner of the domain in Search Console, but I get an error. I responded to the T&S  email with a succinct explanation of the situation. I'll wait and see what the response is.

Comment: Please see edit at bottom of original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically have it covered. But it is important that on new Owner's account, you will need to go to "Billing" in the "hamburger" menu and either link the project to an existing billing account or set up a new Billing account to link the project.

You may also need to delete the old project owner to avoid confusion.